# pytest get pytest.ini to apply regardless of run directory

Tags: python, testing, pytest, markers, working-directory

I'm following a book which tells me to use pytest.ini to declare test method markers.

I found that, in order to exclude a directory under the root (project) directory from test discovery searching I had to put a pytest.ini in that root directory.

When I run `pytest` from the root directory with no selective location regarding test discovery the markers are "found" from the pytest.ini.

But when I run `pytest tests/func` for example, I get "Unknown pytest.mark.xxx - is this a typo?" for all these marks.

If I cd to tests/func and go `pytest`, they are also not found, and I tend to imagine that pytest.ini in the root directory is not "seen" at all.

In fact experimentation shows that when I do `pytest tests/func`, pytest.ini is, similarly, just not being "seen".

At the moment my pytest.ini looks like this:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --ignore=source_dld
markers =
    smoke: marks tests as smoke (deselect with '-m "not smoke"')
    get: bubble
```

How can I make these marker declarations apply, and get my pytest.ini in the project root directory to be "seen", regardless of where the testing is happening?

**Edit**

There's [a page in the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html) about `rootdir` which I've tried to understand. In particular I note

> --rootdir cannot be used with addopts inside pytest.ini because the
> rootdir is used to find pytest.ini already.

So I've tried this kind of thing:

```
...\py_lib2>pytest -rs --rootdir=. tests/func

...\py_lib2>pytest -rs --rootdir="D:\My documents\software projects\EclipseWorkspace\py_lib2" tests/func
```

... pytest.ini in the "project root" dir (py_lib2 here) still ignored. NB OS is W10.

Comment: Could you try `...\py_lib2>pytest -rs --rootdir . tests/func` instead of `...\py_lib2>pytest -rs --rootdir=. tests/func`

Comment: That doesn't work. Please don't guess: if you think something might work, please try it out yourself first. That docs page is quite specific about the `=` sign being the way you are supposed to be able to configure this.

Comment: I have tried and it doesn't need to be `--rootdir=` it can be `--rootdir .`. Only after trying I have asked to check. And its not a guess by the way.

Comment: @mikerodent I am currently having the same problem and do not know how to resolve it. Were you able to make it work?

Comment: Sorry, I have very little recollection of this, and I'm pretty certain that I didn't find a solution.